# -2147467259/Oracle client and networking components were not found

Tags: oracle, vb6, exe

i have used vb6 application with oracle client 11. but at the run exe, i got the below error:

> -2147467259/Oracle client and networking components were not found. These components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of
>   the Oracle Version 7.3.3 or later client software installation.

Provider is unable to function until these components are installed.

Application platform: VB6
Application Type: exe
Window: window 10
Oracle Client version: 11

Comment: can you do a TNSPING from the command line?

Comment: Which Oracle Client did you install? The 32-bit version or the 64-bit version? Please show us your code, esp. the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question and the cause could be a number of different issues. This is likely due to the wrong client version being installed on your machine, and/or it is related to a known issue involving a security update for specific versions of windows. Please see the following Questions on Stack Overflow.

[VB6 application oracle 12 64bit connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46496929/vb6-application-oracle-12-64bit-connection)

[Error ORA-03106 When using VB6 to access Oracle database in Windows 7 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335249/error-ora-03106-when-using-vb6-to-access-oracle-database-in-windows-7-64bit)

[Oracle Client and networking components were not found - Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779100/oracle-client-and-networking-components-were-not-found-excel-vba)

[Connection to Oracle through VBA no longer working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644076/connection-to-oracle-through-vba-no-longer-working)

Here is the Mircosoft support article on the patch issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3126587/ms16-014-description-of-the-security-update-for-windows-vista-windows

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you installed the 64-bit version of Oracle Client 11. VB6 binaries are always 32-but, thus you must install the 32-bit version of Oracle Client.

In case you need both, 32 and 64 bit versions one one machine follow this instruction: [BadImageFormatException. This will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100)

According to your error messages you use the drivers from Microsoft. These drivers are  deprecated for ages, you should prefer the drivers from Oracle.